# Dmarc rule cause a fail of posting to google groups

Tags: spf, dkim, google-groups, dmarc

I have recently added the DMARC rule for my domain and mail server. The policy is set to *none* so that I can analyze the effect of DMARC and SPF before enforcing the reject rule. It works well and it allowed me to identify and fix a small problem.

Yesterday I submitted a mail to a google group by using my email address in my domain instead of using my gmail address as I usually do.

This morning I received DMARC feedback reporting a dkim and spf failure for mails apparently emitted by IPs owned by google.

Does it mean that enforcing SPF, DKIM and DMARC will disable the possibility to use a mailing list like google groups ?

As I don't have any contact at google I don't know what they tried to do. Did they try to send my mail as if it was sent by me without dkim ?

Comment: Do you have access to any of the emails being sent to such a group? If you look at the headers of such an email, you'll probably find that Google adds additional `X-Headers` to the message, such as `X-Original-Authentication-Results`. In my experience, based on those Original Authentication Results, the message will be delivered regardless of whether they fail DMARC at the delivery address.

Comment: Also, Server Fault is a better forum to ask this kind of question, in my opinion. The following question (and its answer) from there will probably help you understand the issue and how Google treats different situations in regards to Google Groups and DMARC.